# Add Multiple ips to a security group using boto3

Tags: boto3

I'm trying to create a script to add serveral IP's to single security group using boto3 but I doubt how to do it. I could add 1 IP using this method:

```
self.public_alb_sg_rule = self.add_resource(ec2.SecurityGroupIngress(
            "443access",
            GroupId=Ref(self.public_alb_sg),
            CidrIp="0.0.0.0/32",
            Description="443access",
            IpProtocol="6",
            FromPort="443",
            ToPort="443"
        ))
```

Is it possible with this pattern?

```
IpPermissions=[
            {'IpProtocol': 'tcp',
             'FromPort': 80,
             'ToPort': 80,
             'IpRanges': [{'CidrIp': '0.0.0.0/0'}]},
            {'IpProtocol': 'tcp',
             'FromPort': 22,
             'ToPort': 22,
             'IpRanges': [{'CidrIp': '0.0.0.0/0'}]}
        ])
```

Doubt on how to proceed this. Appreciate some help with this.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure on how you are calling the boto3 client here since you didn't provide the full code and from what I can understand, you are calling it from your own wrapper class / model.

However, you can call it as such:

```
response = boto3.client('ec2').modify_security_group_rules(
    GroupId='string',
    SecurityGroupRules=[
        {
            'SecurityGroupRuleId': 'string',
            'SecurityGroupRule': {
                'IpProtocol': 'string',
                'FromPort': 123,
                'ToPort': 123,
                'CidrIpv4': 'string',
                'CidrIpv6': 'string',
                'PrefixListId': 'string',
                'ReferencedGroupId': 'string',
                'Description': 'string'
            }
        },
        {
            'SecurityGroupRuleId': 'string',
            'SecurityGroupRule': {
                'IpProtocol': 'string',
                'FromPort': 123,
                'ToPort': 123,
                'CidrIpv4': 'string',
                'CidrIpv6': 'string',
                'PrefixListId': 'string',
                'ReferencedGroupId': 'string',
                'Description': 'string'
            }
        },
        ..
    ]
)
```

You can add all your rules in the array